# where to find my deployed web app on Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, deployment

I am having problem in finding my web-app in apache tomcat's installation directory after being deployed( from eclipse).

Eclipse shows that installation directory of sever is `/usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.47`.
But, i reach there and search under `webapps` folder i can not find my my project there.
`webapps` folder shows `docs  examples  host-manager  manager  ROOT` folders only.

Note- Project is deployed successfully from eclipse and is in running condition.

Please let me know if i am following wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search in your eclipse workspace.**

Workspace-> .metadata -> .plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\ and then tmp[number]\wtpwebapps\project name

Comment: i found my project here, but why this project is not placed in installation directory, Isn't tomcat supposed to read project from its installation directory.

Comment: (up to my knowledge) Actually Eclipse IDE will import an instance of tomcat server and use it as its own. it will not depend on actual installation of tomcat.